# How to query Google Sheet text and number column in one statement

Tags: sql, google-sheets

How can I query a google sheet with both text column and number column together?

Refer to the sheet below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRGvnzccQt6z8wvaPTTn27YAy1tn3_ihuSCG7oKMWxQ/edit?usp=sharing

**Column J** is a text format and **column K** is number, I get the reference cell value as the content in the SQL statement

```
=QUERY(J:L,"SELECT L,J,K WHERE LOWER(J) CONTAINS '"&LOWER($A$1)&"' OR K = '"&$A$1&"'", 0)
```

if I fill the reference cell with text then I have to change the format of column K as Plain text or add the single quote before/after the reference cell in SQL statement, otherwise, I get an error #VALUE!

if I fill the reference cell with value then I have to remove the single quote.

Can anyone advise how I can use one SQL statement to handle both cases?

Best regards,

Kelvin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this as well:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(J:L&"", 
 "select Col3,Col1,Col2 
  where lower(Col1) contains '"&LOWER(A8)&"' 
     or Col2 = '"&A8&""&"'", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, it works. may I know why only Col can work but not C,D, etc?

Comment: @Kelvin its because we manipulated range `J:L` and added nothing to it `&""`. query can read only clear range with `"select A,B..."`. every constructed range needs to use `Col` references (`"select Col1,Col2..."`)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

`=QUERY(J:L,"SELECT L,J,K WHERE LOWER(J) CONTAINS '"&LOWER($A$1)&"' OR K = '"&$A$8&"' ", 0)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
=QUERY(J:L,"SELECT L,J,K WHERE LOWER(J) CONTAINS '"&LOWER($A$8)&"' OR K = "&$A$8&" ", 0)
```

**You only need single quotes around text.**

Comment: It can't, it returns #VALUE! if I input text, it can only work for number input